# implementing swipe for next item horizontal Listview in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, swipe

I want to implement swipe for next item in horizontal list view in flutter instead of using view pager, cause it doesn't fit my design.

like the way horizontal list view in google app store

this is my code

```
   return ListView.separated(
   separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return SizedBox(height: 3);
   },
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
   itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => (AlAinPdtItem(
      title: snapshot.data[i].title,
      imgUrl: snapshot.data[i].imgUrl,
      price: snapshot.data[i].price,
      pdt2: snapshot.data[i])),
);
```

Comment: what is the issue you get after using pageView

Comment: adding viewportFraction is missing up my design

Comment: can you include an image, and you can get it with ListView by Guesturedetector on horzontalDragUpdate